# Writing XML file to computer in Java

Tags: java, xml

So I have the following code, where I want to create a XML file and store it locally on my computer, however whenever I execute the code, it doesn't seem to be saving the file, can someone please help me?

```
public void CreateXMLPoll (Poll p) {

        try {
            // Initialize the XML builder
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

            // Set the Elements Up
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Poll");
            Element creator = doc.createElement("Creator");
            Element name = doc.createElement("Name");
            Element email = doc.createElement("Email");
            Element title = doc.createElement("Title");
            Element location = doc.createElement("Location");
            Element description = doc.createElement("Description");
            Element date = doc.createElement("Date");
            Element time = doc.createElement("Time");

            // Create XML tree
            rootElement.appendChild(creator);
            rootElement.appendChild(title);
            rootElement.appendChild(location);
            rootElement.appendChild(description);
            rootElement.appendChild(date);
            creator.appendChild(name);
            creator.appendChild(email);
            date.appendChild(time);

            // Add values to XML
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(p.getUsername()));
            email.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(p.getEmail()));
            title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(p.getTitle()));
            location.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(p.getLocation()));
            description.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(p.getDescription()));

            // Appends a bunch of dates
            for (PollDates pd : p.getDates()) {
                time.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(pd.getFirst().toString()));
                if (pd.getSecond() != null) time.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(pd.getSecond().toString()));
                if (pd.getThird() != null) time.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(pd.getThird().toString()));
            }

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("test.xml");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/testing.xml"));

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I followed a tutorial off [here](http://t.genedavis.com/library/xml/java_dom_xml_creation.jsp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this line,

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

You need to have statement as :

```
out.write("content to write in the file");
```

to write the file.

To get the content, you missed this from your tutorial:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
trans.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Once you have the `xmlString`, write in the file using:

```
out.write(xmlString,0, xmlString.length);
```

Once done, you need to add,

```
out.close();
```

to close the stream.

Update the program and try.

Comment: once I've written to file, where do I save it?

Comment: You are saving the file already at root location from where you are running the program. Search "test.xml" in root folder. If trouble finding it, try giving absolute path of the file as `FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter`(`"C:/test.xml");`. In this case file will be generated at `C:/test.xml`

Comment: that worked, however my code only generates `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` and nothing else

Comment: Try printing/debugging `xmlString` and `doc` contents before writing into XML(towards the end). I am suspecting, the object you created in the top with nodes, were not associated with `doc` which is being used for writing.

Answer (score 2):

I will reccommend you to use JAXB

**with JAXB that you can:**

- Generate JAXB Java classes from an XML schema
- Use schema-derived JAXB classes to unmarshal and marshal XML content
  in a Java application
- Create a Java content tree using schema-derived JAXB classes
- Validate XML content during unmarshalling and at runtime
- Customize JAXB schema-to-Java bindings

**Check this Example**

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

It is more easy, redable code, object oriented approach.

Comment: using this example though, how would you create child nodes? I have a list of objects that need to be printed out as child nodes

Comment: have you seen example given here http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html